# In a scatterplot, how do I plot a line that is an average of the all vertical coordinates of datapoints that has the same x coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I want something like the plots shown in figure below, where the blue line is the average  line that is generated by plotting the mean of all y-coordinate values of data-points that have the same x-coordinate values.

[image: Fig-1]

I tried the code below

```
window_size = 10
df_avg = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for col in df.columns:
    df_avg[col] = df[col].rolling(window=window_size).mean()

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1):
    plt.subplot(df.shape[1]-4, 4, idx)
    sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=col, y='charges')
    plt.plot(df_avg[col],df['charges'])
    plt.xlabel(col)
```

And, got plots shown below, which obviously, is not what I wanted.
[image: Fig-2]

Comment: You probably want https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html

Comment: Your first problem will be to define what "having the same x-coordinate" means, because you are dealing with floating numbers so equality does not work and you have to play around with tolerances instead.

Comment: @Guimoute, the data showed in this specific question looks pretty categorical: year, age, number of children,sex, etc. So floating numbers shouldn't be an issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a purely matplotlib way to do it. Here is a possible direction you can take:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

### Create toy dataset consisting of (500,2) points
N_points=500
rand_pts=np.random.choice(50,size=(N_points,2))

#create a dictionary with keys the unique x values and values the different y values corresponding to this unique x
rand_dict={uni:rand_pts[np.where(rand_pts[:,0]==uni),1] for uni in np.unique(rand_pts[:,0])}

#plot
plt.scatter(rand_pts[:,0],rand_pts[:,1],s=50) #plot the scatter plot
plt.plot(list(rand_dict.keys()),[np.mean(val) for val in rand_dict.values()],color='tab:orange',lw=4) #plot the mean y values for each unique x
```

[image]